# ASP.NET OracleDataAdapter.Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема с обновлением страницы после добавления записи в таблицу. На странице есть GridView и в нём таблица из базы данных Oracle 11g xe. Я добавляю новую запись, но что бы увидеть её мне приходится обновить страницу вручную. Почему то код обновления не работает. Вот мой код

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(web.Personel_Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text), con);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from PERSONEL", con);
    con = da.SelectCommand.Connection;
    OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "PERSONEL");
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["PERSONEL"];
    da.Update(dt);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    con.Open();

    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(web.Personel_Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text), con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    /* кода, который привязывает данные к GridView, в вопросе нет
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from PERSONEL", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "PERSONEL");
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["PERSONEL"];
    */   
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: А при чём тут это? Данные в таблицу просто помещены путём добавления sqldatasource через мастер вот и всё. Мне нужно понять что я не так делаю при обновлении.

Comment: @Андрей Как контрол узнает, что Вы вставили запись в таблицу базы? Где/когда вызывается `DataBind`?

Comment: `con.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from PERSONEL", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();`                                                                                            Я попробовал сделать добавление в таблицу ещё вот так. Но так почему то нечего не происходит. В этом случае апдейт сработает? Но тогда что не так в моём добавлении? или как можно обновить страницу по другому в моём первом варианте?

Comment: @Андрей Здорово. И где же находится этот замечательный код?

Comment: То что я скинул в последний раз пробовал делать и в пейдж лоде и выносить отдельно в функцию а её уже использовать в пейджлоде. Но и так и так нечего не выходит.

Comment: @Андрей Потому что `Page_Load` выполняется гораздо раньше, чем `Button1_Click`. Вызовите Вашу функцию еще раз в `Button1_Click` - после вставки записи.

Comment: Да дело не в том что пейдж лод раньше баттона. У меня грид вью пустой. В том то и дело что если добавление в таблицу идёт в пейдж лоде. То когда страница загружается грид должен быть уже наполнен данными. Но грид пустой что в моём коде добавления который я скинул в комментарии не так? Это не тот же код что в вопросе если что. В вопросе код апдейта. А тут код добавления.

Comment: Что за тон? Если Вас не устраивает то, что я пишу, - ждите других ответов.

Comment: Вообще то я пытаюсь донести что мне нужно. А вы последний раз написали не то что я спросил.

Comment: @Андрей Вы плохо пытаетесь. В коде вопроса нет апдейта, а в коде в комментарии - нет добавления.

Comment: Ну если так тогда по моему вы плохо разбираетесь. Спасибо за помощь.